# What's a word, phrase, or idiom that describes something between 'too scared' and 'too dumb'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

There's a sentence (from a screenplay) that says "*Bart, we’re literally here buying you drugs cus you’re not able to buy your own high*"

I want to replace the words "not able" with something better. It needs to connote that the person is too scared but also too stupid to do this on his own, so it'd be on the spectrum between the two. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's arguable that scaredness and intelligence are orthogonal. If so, there will be no spectrum / gradience, and the question is akin to asking for a term meaning both 'too heavy and 'too pink'.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 1):

> "Bart, we’re literally here buying you drugs cus you’re **too chicken** to buy your own high"

From [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Too%20Chicken), which for once, provides a decent definition

> ### too chicken
>
> When someone is too much of a *pussy* to do something. When they don't have the guts or balls to do whatever it is you are referring to. This phrase can also be used for yourself, you are referring to the fact that you don't have it in you to face whatever it is. You or (They) are too chicken to do it.

Moreover, chickens are not notorious for being clever animals.

Comment: yeah this is pretty good

Answer (score 1):

> "Bart, we’re literally here buying you drugs cus you’re ***incapable*** *of buying* your own high."

From [Merriam-Webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incapable):

### incapable

1. : lacking capacity, ability, or qualification for the purpose or end
   in view: such as

   a : not able or fit for the doing or performance : INCOMPETENT
2. : lacking legal qualification or power (as by reason of mental
   incompetence) : DISQUALIFIED

Answer (score 0):

"panicky" may fit the bill, as it implies unreasoning and overpowering fear, making one unable to act astutely  in an emergency.

[**panicky**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/panicky) - "thrown into a state of intense fear or desperation"

Answer (score 0):

> **pathetic** ([Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pathetic))

1. Arousing pity, especially through vulnerability or sadness
2. Miserably inadequate; of very low standard

...where *in practice*, that "vulnerability" is often ***fearfulness***, and/or the "inadequacy" is ***lack of brains or common sense***.